How to integrate the guidewire G Unit testing utility in jenkins
How to integrate the guidewire G Unit testing utility in Jenkins. I tried to found the relevant doc but no luck.

You can run unit tests through Jenkins by adding a step for unit testing to your pipeline that runs the below command
gwb test (Windows Server)
or
./gwb test (Linux server)
This will run all unit tests, which may not be your intention and it may take a large amount of time to run all unit tests depending on your application. To run selective test suites you can use the below command
gwb runSuite -Dsuite=acme.cc.AcmeServerTestSuite -Ddir.results=modules\configuration\build\testresults\
AcmeServerTestSuite

dir.results is used to specify the directory where unit test results are stored. This file can be saved in an artifactory for consumption by a system that shows test results for each pipeline run.
You can even get metrics like code coverage using Jacoco or a similar plugin, the details of which are documented here (requires login).

Apologize for the late reply. Will the Jetty server get started when we invoke the "gwb runSuite" command in the Jenkins slave machine? Also should we need to pass any arguments ( which is used in the studio server config ) to the "gwb runSuite" command?
